# Time proportional control

Tags: controls, temperature

I am developing application for Time Proportional Control. I know that the output is proportional to an error. For example, if SetPoint is 20 and proportional band is 2, in case if actual temperature (AT) is 19, then Output would be 50%. However, I can not figure out what happens if AT is higher than 20? For example if AT is 21, then output would be again 50%, that does not make any sense.

Comment: Can the output be negative? I imagine this is suppose to control a heater or air conditioner of some variety; can it cool as well as heat, and if so, what would the output look like to make it do so?

Comment: It is temperature control. There is only heater, not any cooling system

Comment: In that case, if the AT is higher then the set point, is there anything you can do but wait?

Comment: So, `if( AT >= SP ) { output = 0; }`.

Comment: Currently I am just turning off heater completely if AC is higher than SetPoint

Comment: Right, that's what I was trying to say. That sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: But in that case if temperature hits 20, for the next cycle(10 mins) heater will not work and temperature decreases widely...

Comment: By the way, this site is oriented towards very programming-specific questions, along the lines of "my code won't compile" and "how do I use C++ templates in this instance", etc. While this question I think fits here, you might get more useful responses from people with more experience in control theory than yours truly. May I suggest trying http://robotics.stackexchange.com, http://electronics.stackexchange.com, or possibly http://scicomp.stackexchange.com?

Comment: It is 0 if they are equal